# How to change date format in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working with reactjs and i am using "nextjs" framework, I am fetching "blogs data" using loop, but problem is "i want to change date format of blogs"
Here is my current code

```
{user && user.length > 0 && user.map((userObj, index) => (
                      <NewsCard
                    key={index}
                    img={userObj.image}
                    title={userObj.title}
                    date={userObj.CreatedAt}   // getting date for example "2023-03-26 01:40:26"
        />
                ))}
```

My expected date format is for example
`April 29,2023`
How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `toLocaleDateString()` method to convert the date

```
{user && user.length > 0 && user.map((userObj, index) => (
    <NewsCard
        key={index}
        img={userObj.image}
        title={userObj.title}
        date={new Date(userObj.CreatedAt).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
            month: 'long',
            day: 'numeric',
            year: 'numeric',
        })}
    />
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Date.toLocaleString()` and specifiy the desired format with it:

```js
const date=new Date().toLocaleString("en-US",{month:"long", day:"numeric", year:"numeric"});

console.log(date)
```

So, I guess, in your React pag you should put something like

```
date={userObj.Created.toLocaleString("en-US",{month:"long", day:"numeric", year:"numeric"})}
```